# ActionBarSherlock library is full of errors after being imported

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar

Okay, I'm trying to get ActionBarSherlock working, so I imported the library by:

```
Creating New Project > Create Project From Existing Source > Choosing library from the ActionBarSherlock folder
```

After that I imported a example project from the samples folder using the same method, Both the library and the sample are set to Android 15 Build Path!

My problem is, over 100 errors come up in the library, all kinds of stuff about Call requires api level 11, And I have no idea whats wrong!

Things I have tried: 
Cleaning Project
Setting build path to 13, 14 and 15

Most of the errors say:

```
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.app.something
```

Update: I tried right clicking on the lib file and clicking add to build path, that didnt work, these are a few of the errors that I'm getting:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method add(CharSequence) of type MenuWrapper must override a superclass method  MenuWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 33 Java Problem
The method add(int, int, int, CharSequence) of type MenuWrapper must override a superclass method   MenuWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 43 Java Problem
The method add(int, int, int, int) of type MenuWrapper must override a superclass method    MenuWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 48 Java Problem
The method add(int) of type MenuWrapper must override a superclass method   MenuWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 38 Java Problem
The method addIntentOptions(int, int, int, ComponentName, Intent[], Intent, int, MenuItem[]) of type MenuWrapper must override a superclass method  MenuWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 81 Java Problem
The method addOnAttachStateChangeListener(View_OnAttachStateChangeListener) of type ActionMenuItemView must override a superclass method    ActionMenuItemView.java /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 84 Java Problem
The method addOnAttachStateChangeListener(View_OnAttachStateChangeListener) of type ActionMenuPresenter.OverflowMenuButton must override a superclass method    ActionMenuPresenter.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 627    Java Problem
The method addSubMenu(CharSequence) of type MenuWrapper must override a superclass method   MenuWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 61 Java Problem
The method addSubMenu(int, int, int, CharSequence) of type MenuWrapper must override a superclass method    MenuWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 71 Java Problem
The method addSubMenu(int, int, int, int) of type MenuWrapper must override a superclass method MenuWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 76 Java Problem
The method addSubMenu(int) of type MenuWrapper must override a superclass method    MenuWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 66 Java Problem
The method clear() of type MenuWrapper must override a superclass method    MenuWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 101    Java Problem
The method clearHeader() of type SubMenuWrapper must override a superclass method   SubMenuWrapper.java /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 49 Java Problem
The method close() of type MenuWrapper must override a superclass method    MenuWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 157    Java Problem
The method collapseActionView() of type ActionMenuItem must override a superclass method    ActionMenuItem.java /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 264    Java Problem
The method collapseActionView() of type MenuItemImpl must override a superclass method  MenuItemImpl.java   /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 612    Java Problem
The method collapseActionView() of type MenuItemWrapper must override a superclass method   MenuItemWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 254    Java Problem
The method collapseItemActionView(MenuBuilder, MenuItemImpl) of type ActionBarView.ExpandedActionViewMenuPresenter must override a superclass method    ActionBarView.java  /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget    line 1497   Java Problem
The method describeContents() of type ActionMenuPresenter.SavedState must override a superclass method  ActionMenuPresenter.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 557    Java Problem
The method expandActionView() of type ActionMenuItem must override a superclass method  ActionMenuItem.java /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 259    Java Problem
The method expandActionView() of type MenuItemImpl must override a superclass method    MenuItemImpl.java   /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 598    Java Problem
The method expandActionView() of type MenuItemWrapper must override a superclass method MenuItemWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 249    Java Problem
The method expandItemActionView(MenuBuilder, MenuItemImpl) of type ActionBarView.ExpandedActionViewMenuPresenter must override a superclass method  ActionBarView.java  /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget    line 1471   Java Problem
The method findItem(int) of type MenuWrapper must override a superclass method  MenuWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 127    Java Problem
The method flagActionItems() of type ActionBarView.ExpandedActionViewMenuPresenter must override a superclass method    ActionBarView.java  /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget    line 1466   Java Problem
The method flagActionItems() of type MenuPopupHelper must override a superclass method  MenuPopupHelper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 280    Java Problem
The method getActionProvider() of type ActionMenuItem must override a superclass method ActionMenuItem.java /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 243    Java Problem
The method getActionProvider() of type MenuItemWrapper must override a superclass method    MenuItemWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 240    Java Problem
The method getActionView() of type MenuItemWrapper must override a superclass method    MenuItemWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 229    Java Problem
The method getAlphabeticShortcut() of type MenuItemWrapper must override a superclass method    MenuItemWrapper.java    /com_actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/view/menu line 123    Java Problem
```

Comment: Can you name at least a few specific errors?

Comment: @AlexLockwood sorry, it had about 150 of them and they all said something different. I added more errors

Answer (score 54, accepted):

- Go to Project Properties > Java Compiler. Use JDK 1.6.
- Ensure you're compiling both the library and your app with Android 4.0+
- Ensure your targetSdkVersion is 14 or higher.

Comment: Thanks sooo much, that worked! :D I had it set on JDK 1.5. p.s. ActionBarSherlock is totally awesome!

Comment: @Jake Wharton is the creator of that awesome library...  We should all be thankful  to him...

Comment: This should be in the FAQ. You deserve a medal.

Comment: Thank you so much...you are great...you saved lots of time of mine to involve in this issue.. you really deserve a medal

Answer (score 6):

1. In the project explorer, locate the `android-support-v4.jar` file in the `libs` directory. Right click this file and add it to your build path with:

   <kbd>Build path</kbd> --> <kbd>Add to build path</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

right click, select properties, java build path, libraries tab, click Add Libraries... and Add JRE System Library 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Right click, select Properties, Java Build Path, Libraries tab; click "Add Libraries" and add "JRE System Library 1.6".

Confirm the modification, and remove the JRE System Library you added later.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the new library manifest package is "com.actionbarsherlock"

(Maybe It's just me, but I created the project on top of where i had already extracted the library folder.)