# Many error ins src in ActionBarSherlock after importing

Tags: actionbarsherlock

Hi I have a problem with the ActionBarSherlock after importing.

I made the following steps:

- I Imported the stuff from the library folder
- I checked if the project is set as IsLibrary
- I selected Project Build target: Android 4.0

then the project look like this:
[image]

I dont know whats wrong, the error in the first package e.g. is:

```
The method onCreatePanelMenu(int, Menu) of type Watson must override a superclass method
```

Comment: setting up the java compiler to 1.6 fixed the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ActionBarSherlock library is full of errors after being imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165700/actionbarsherlock-library-is-full-of-errors-after-being-imported)

Answer (score 1):

There May be other ways, My Suggestion is to go to java file and remove all `@override` symbols above the methods there, because I have also faced that problem and I did that to get rid of those errors! I think this may meet your need.